# File not converting to JSON properly from xml

Tags: python, json, xml, converters, xmltodict

I am using Python to convert data from a xml file to json and putting it in a file. I am using xmltodict to convert to dictionary using 'parse' and then converting into json using 'dumps'. Here is the code below: -

```
import xmltodict
import json
with open('note.xml') as xml_file:
    my_dict=xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
xml_file.close()
json_data=json.dumps(my_dict)
with open('note.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f)
```

[Here is a sample xml file that I have used](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml). However, in the output, I am getting something not quite json like, with the added backslash. Looks like gibberish: -

```
"{\"note\": {\"to\": \"Tove\", \"from\": \"Jani\", \"heading\": \"Reminder\", \"body\": \"Don't forget me this weekend!\"}}"
```

I am trying to understand why I am not able to get data in proper json form. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please note that I am not a very skilled programmer and have only used Python sporadically.

Comment: That is not gibbereish. It is proper json. The inner double quotes are backslashed as its in a string surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Do a json.loads on the string and print the json and you should be able to see it in json format

Comment: The JSON written seems to be fine but you are doing double conversion. First you create string with 'json.dumps' and the you write that string with 'json.dump'. Just write it directly with 'json.dump(my_dict, f)' Otherwise you are writing just string as JSON and the quotes get escaped as in proper JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below code after `json_data=json.dumps(my_dict)` to convert string to json object

```
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
```